# How to map gdate to date in a docker alpine container / busybox?

Tags: docker, busybox, alpine-linux

I have created a Centos7 docker container for checking the expiry date of some certificates.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -q -y install openssl && \
  ln -s /usr/bin/date /bin/gdate
```

The check of the certificates is done by a shell script which was developed on macos. Therefore I need to map `gdate` to `date`, as `gdate` is only available on macos and not on centos.

This container is quite huge with around 200MB. I've tried the `alpine` image and map `gdate` there:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
  apk add --no-cache openssl && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
  ln -s /bin/date /bin/gdate
```

When testing inside the alpine container I get:

```
/ # gdate
gdate: applet not found
```

How do I map `gdate` to `date` in the docker alpine container / busybox?

Answer (score 1):

The way you create symbolic link does not work in busybox. If you run `ls -l /bin` in your container, you'll see something strange, like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 ash -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 base64 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 bbconfig -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        805024 Dec 12 10:42 busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 cat -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 chgrp -> /bin/busybox
...
```

Every file except `/bin/busybox` itself is symbolic link to the file `/bin/busybox`.

You can see the file `busybox` is some kind of command multiplexer. When you run the `date` command, you're actually running `busybox date`.

To map `gdate` to `date`, create a shell script named `gdate` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
busybox date
```

And make it executable. Then in your Dockerfile, `COPY` it to the image:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
apk add --no-cache openssl && \
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY gdate /bin/
```

And build.

Comment: Thanks. How would you add the script inline to the Dockerfile? I don't know how to escacpe `#!/bin/sh`. I've tried `echo "#!/bin/sh\n busybox date" > /bin/date"` but it breaks after the first line

Comment: It is created outside the Dockerfile. In Dockerfile I just copy it.

Comment: I know, but I'd rather like to have all inside the dockerfile instead of having two files.

Comment: Try `RUN printf "#!/bin/sh\nbusybox date\n" > /bin/date`. I've tested on my Mac.